# Using an iterator template class as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, template-classes

```
return Graph_iterator_Vertex(Vertexs.begin());
```

I do not understand why this line is called the copy constructor, although there is my constructor with a parameter. The arguments constructor parameter written specifically for this design.
All that I have found about a similar issue is the use of typename. But it did not solve my problem.

```
struct Graph_iterator_Vertex
    {
    private:
        typename std::vector<Vertex<Type_Of_Value_Vertex, Type_Of_Value_Edge>>::iterator iterator;

    public:

        Graph_iterator_Vertex(typename std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::vector<Vertex<Type_Of_Value_Vertex, Type_Of_Value_Edge>>> iterator_)

        {
            iterator=iterator_
        }
    };

    const Graph_iterator_Vertex begin(void) const 
    {
        return Graph_iterator_Vertex(Vertexs.begin()); 
    }
```

where

```
std::vector<Vertex<Type_Of_Value_Vertex, Type_Of_Value_Edge>> Vertexs;
```

Error:

```
error C2440: <function-style-cast>: can not be converted std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>"in "Graph<Type_Of_Value_Vertex,Type_Of_Value_Edge>::Graph_iterator_Vertex"
```

Comment: Know the difference between `iterator` and `const_iterator`. Also know what `const` member function (such as `begin` in your code) does to the member data (such as `Vertexs`; note it changes it const-ness!) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
std::vector<Vertex<Type_Of_Value_Vertex, Type_Of_Value_Edge>>::const_iterator
```

instead of

```
std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::vector<Vertex<Type_Of_Value_Vertex, Type_Of_Value_Edge>>>
```

as the type of your function parameter.

Comment: O, sorry. I did not notice the const. Thank you.

Comment: @ggoha the `std::_Vector_const_iterator` type doesn't have a proper constructor for such conversion.